# How to calculate $\frac d{dx}x^x$ without differentiating any logarithms?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to calculate $\frac d{dx}x^x$ without differentiating any logarithms?  There isn't any clear derivative rule I can use and the derivative quotients aren't any help:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\text{ or }\lim_{h\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}$$

I was wondering if there were any ways to do this using either power rule or derivatives of exponential functions.

---

To be more concise as to what I mean here, as pointed out by the comments, I could just write $x^x=e^{x\ln(x)}$.  However, that would involve taking the derivative of a logarithm.  One may use $\frac d{dx}a^x=\ln(a)a^x$, which seems intuitive, since if we could somehow change the $a$ to an $x$, we'd almost have the correct derivative.  Though I haven't the slightest of how one would formally do that.

Comment: Since $x^x$ is **defined** via a logarithm there is no way you can avoid logs.

Comment: You can write $x^x = e^{x\log x}$ and use the chain rule, the product rule, and the rules for differentiating $e^x$ and $\log x$.

Comment: @LeBtz I doubt that is true.  And how do you define it so?  Or did you mean that it had a logarithm in it?  Just because it has a logarithm in the derivative does not mean you can't take the derivative without logarithmic differentiation.

Comment: @JackLee Well, I mean, I don't want to go that path (since its basically logarithmic differentiation).

Comment: I often use this way in fact similar to log differentation. Use $e^{x\ln x}$ and chain rule.

Comment: The definition of $a^x$ for $a>0$ is $\exp(x\log(a))$. What definition do you use if it is not that one?

Comment: Another cute approach is to use the multivariable chain rule on the function $u(s,t) = s^t$.  It's clear that $u_s = ts^{t-1}$ and $u_t = s^t \ln s$.  Then $f(x) = u(x,x)$, so $f'(x) = u_s(x,x) + u_t(x,x) = x x^{x-1} + x^x \ln x = x^x(1+\ln x)$.

Comment: @LeBtz Ugh no, that is not the definition for $a^x$.  Then you'd need to define $\operatorname{exp}$.  I usually define it as the product of $x$ amount of $a$'s axiomatically extended through exponential rules for $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @SimpleArt How is it "basically" logarithmic differentiation? Logarithmic differentiation involves implicit differentiation; differentiating $\exp (x \log x)$ is very much explicit .

Comment: @NateEldredge Hm, I'm not familiar with multivariable calculus.  That sounds interesting.

Comment: @SimpleArt $\exp$ is defined via $\exp(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$. Your definition doesn't make sense however. You can extend it that way for $x\in \mathbb Q$ but not for $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @LeBtz If you add continuity.  I meant that as well, and I think you can still take derivatives for functions defined for $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Simple Art: it is not obvious, in that case, that $2^x$ is differentiable at all... A standard way to define functions like $2^x$ in continuous settings is to define $\exp(x)$ via a power series (so it is clear that it is differentiable) and then define $2^x$ as $\exp(x \log 2)$.

Comment: @LeBtz IMHO when $x$ is irrational $a^x$ should be defined as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{r_n}$ where $(r_n)$ is an increasing rational sequence with limit $x$ ($a\geq1$) and then $a^x:=\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{-x}$ ($0<a<1$) This is the most natural way to extend exponentiation.

Comment: @Guest: as I was pointing out, however, it is not obvious that a function defined that way will be differentiable. For example $f(x) = |x-\pi|$ as a function from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable "over $\mathbb{Q}$" at every rational input, and it extends to a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but that function is not differentiable everywhere. This is why the method you described is not often used as a definition of $a^x$ in continuous settings - the definition via a power series is easier to work with.

Comment: @JackLee Thank you for pointing that.  I've updated the question to involve no differentiation of logarithms.  Of course a logarithm should show up in the answer, but it is perfectly possible for logarithms to show up without differentiating any to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that we can write

$$(x+h)^{x+h}=x^{x+h}\left(1+\frac hx\right)^{x+h} \tag 1$$

Expanding the parenthetical term on the right-hand side of $(1)$ in a generalized [Binomial Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Proof) reveals

$$\left(1+\frac hx\right)^{x+h}=1+\frac{h(x+h)}{x}+O(h^2) \tag 2$$

Putting together $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields

$$\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-x^x}{h}=x^x\left(\frac{x^h-1}{h}\right)+x^xx^h+O(h)$$

Taking the limit as $h\to 0$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{(x+h)^{x+h}-x^x}{h}\right)&=x^x\left(1+\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{x^h-1}{h}\right)\right)\\\\
&=x^x(1+\log(x))
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: This is new for me.  +1

Comment: @paramanandsingh Thank you my friend!  Much appreciative.  This was new for me also.  I'd not seen this.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer.  :)

Comment: You're welcome!  It was my pleasure. -Mark